# Switch <Img> source based on data-theme

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dark-mode system built into my website but I can't figure out how to switch the image source. I'm using the Javascript below with no problems for a bunch of other variables (mostly color but also element positions, etc), I just need to add something for the img src but I'm not sure what to do next.

### Code

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
  }
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```html
<picture class="swoop">
  <source srcset="assets/landingContentSwoopDark.png">
  <img src="assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png ">
</picture>
```

EDIT:

I tried the answer below with some changes for my particular case and it still isn't working, but I'm guessing that's due to what I changed. Here is the updated code:

```
<div class="theme-switch-wrapper col-md-3">
    <label class="theme-switch switch pull-right" for="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

<script>
    const image = document.querySelector('.swoopImage');
    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
            image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopDark.png';
        }
        else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
            image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png';
        }
    }

    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
    </script>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="swoop">
    <img style="margin-top: -53%; position: relative; pointer-events: none;" class="swoopImage" src="assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you using var `--bg-swoop` exactly? How does class `swoop` know to use the dynamic URL ?

Comment: I agree to @Kalnode . What's the use of `--bg-swoop` in the first place and how are you trying to achieve the swapping?

Comment: Sorry, that is all graveyard stuff of things I've tried that haven't worked. I'm not using them anywhere, I thought I might be able to use a var() inside the HTML but my google-fu hasn't shown me that its possible. I can remove it if it's confusing.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using CSS var's to hold global data; you just have to leverage it appropriately. You can access CSS var's in different ways, even in JS. Personally, things like resource URL's I keep in JS global stores, because often they may be fed from an API or database. Meanwhile CSS var's I tend to only use for actual raw theme values like colors and paddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Given your code, I think it's because of the use of `picture` tag as it uses the first one if possible else it falls back to the next ones, and since your first image works it does not goes to next one. And then to switch the images you are changing the `--bg-swoop` variable through which you wanted to switch background image (I assume) but that's not how this works. To change the source of the image you need to use JS to change the value in `src` of the image.

### Solution

There are some vague places. SO assuming you want to just swap the image based on Toggle dark mode, you can use the following:

```js
if (toggle.checked) {
    image.src = 'path/to/image-on-check.png';
} else {
    image.src = 'path/to/image-on-un-check.png';
}
```

and as for HTML, you can only have a image tag:

```html
<img id="image" src="path/to/image-on-un-check.png" alt="Image">
```

### Demo

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
const image = document.getElementById('image');

toggle.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (toggle.checked) {
    image.src = 'https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/692536747/5f5045c4-56a9-4dfc-ab63-6605677a0711';
  } else {
    image.src = 'https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/711272363/eed53990-6c00-421c-98ae-daf8590d9481';
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="toggle">Toggle Image:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<img id="image" src="https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/711272363/eed53990-6c00-421c-98ae-daf8590d9481" alt="Image">
```

### For your case

For your particular case, the code would be:

```js
const image = document.querySelector('.swoop');
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopDark.png';
  } else {
    image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png';
  }
}


toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```html
<img class="swoop" src="assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png" alt="Image">
```

Hope that works.

---

### Edit

To make sure the code runs no matter where the script tag is, you can do:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const image = document.querySelector('.swoop');
    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
    
    function switchTheme(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopDark.png';
      } else {
        image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png';
      }
    }
    
    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
});
```

So the code will run after the window loads properly

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to change some things and it still isn't working, so it's probably on my side of the stuff I changed. I edited the main post with what I've changed so far.

Comment: Can you also provide the toggle buttons HTML?

Comment: Okay, so I tried your code, and it did work for me tho

Comment: Oh very strange. Yes I'll edit the post with the toggleswitch HTML. Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the problem, the `script` tag is nested inside a bunch of divs, while the `swoop` div is outside the next further down. Could that be affecting it?

Comment: Update: the script tag needed to be below both divs, which is obvious now in hindsight. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, @ThatBraxGuy is correct... And the best way to do that is to add an onload eventlistener to window. That way it won't matter where the script tag is. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this quite differently than you are currently doing.

I would have the page theme determined by which CSS classes are in use and then just toggle the CSS classes when the theme needs to be changed.

When it comes to swapping images, I would set the image as a background on an element, rather than use `picture` or `img` because background images can be set with CSS.

Here is an example:

```js
const themeImg = document.querySelector("div.img");

document.querySelector(".themeWrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // event.target represents the radio button that initiated the event (got clicked)
  if(event.target.value === "dark"){
    // Just switch classes to change themes
    document.body.classList.remove("light");
    document.body.classList.add("dark");
    themeImg.classList.remove("light");
    themeImg.classList.add("dark");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.add("light");
    document.body.classList.remove("dark");
    themeImg.classList.add("light");
    themeImg.classList.remove("dark");
  }
});
```

```css
/* Standard Styles */
div.img {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Default theme (light) */
body.light {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

div.img.light { 
  background:url(https://png-3.vector.me/files/images/6/9/697797/acid_smiley_face_vector_free_preview.png);
}

/* Alternate theme (dark) */
body.dark {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

div.img.dark { 
  background:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQaTmuzhVLgp7J9I85SBrR29znZb2i0syZR1g&usqp=CAU);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Themed Page</title>
</head>
<body class="light">
  <p>Choose a theme</p>
  <div class="themeWrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="theme" value="light" checked>Light &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="theme" value="dark">Dark
  </div>

  <div class="img light"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no need to style each element separately, otherwise you'll end up with a good load of useless and hard-to-maintain JS styling. Just toggle the body data attribute or a class and use i.e. something like `.dark .img { /* dark mode .img styles here */ }` instead of JS. Also, there's absolutely no need to use two styles/classes. Just one.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Agreed. This is just an example to demonstrate the approach as opposed to what the OP is currently doing.